# mkisofs - Floppy Image to Disk Image

Tags: windows, batch-file, iso

I'm trying to compile [MikeOS](http://mikeos.berlios.de/) on windows. I've successfully (I think) created a floppy (.flp) image of the operating system. I want to convert it to a disk image (.iso) so I can run it in virtual box. I've tried

```
mkisofs -quiet -V 'MIKEOS' -input-charset iso8859-1 -o disk_images/mikeos.iso -b mikeos.flp disk_images/
```

Which is the command in the Linux build script. It does create an ISO image, but when I try to run in in VirtualBox, I get a black screen. What am I doing wrong? [Here's my build script.](http://pastebin.com/uZSdjCDJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to create a bootable CD-rom from a bootable floppy, that'd involve some complexity around [El Torito](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_%28CD-ROM_standard%29).

Just add a floppy controller!

Go into your VM's preferences, choose *Storage*, right-click on the storage tree and *Add Floppy Controller*. Then *Add Floppy Device*, pick the floppy image you generated (rename it to `.raw` if needed).